# Getting null Value when executing a SQL Server stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am executing a SQL Server stored procedure in C#, but both my output parameters are returned blank. But when I run this stored procedure directly in SSMS, then I get values for both parameters. I used same input order no.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code? Thank you

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("wt_find_open_pick_ticket_count", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input_order_no", order_no);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@results", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters["@results"].Value.ToString());
}

ALTER procedure wt_find_open_pick_ticket_count
@input_order_no varchar(20),
@results varchar(1000) OUTPUT,
@status int OUTPUT

AS

SELECT
status = 
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no)>0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END,
results = 

CASE
    WHEN COUNT(oe_pick_ticket.pick_ticket_no)> 0 THEN 'Message'
    ELSE ''
    END

    FROM oe_pick_ticket with (nolock)

    WHERE
    oe_pick_ticket.order_no = @input_order_no
    AND oe_pick_ticket.invoice_no IS NULL 
    AND oe_pick_ticket.delete_flag = 'N'
    AND oe_pick_ticket.print_date > '2014-01-01'


    GROUP BY oe_pick_ticket.order_no
```

Comment: Can you share your stored procedure with us?

Comment: Is your stored procedure a SELECT?  You've got ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: We need to see your SP as your C# looks fine.

Comment: Hi,
I have added my SP under C# code

Comment: The procedure never assigns anything to the output parameters, so they'll be null whenever you call it.

Comment: Did you truncate the text of your SP or are you missing the @ symbol on your parameters? "SELECT status=..." should be "SELECT @status=..." The same goes for "results".

Comment: "But when I run this stored procedure directly in SSMS, then I get values for both parameters"...based on what you've shown, I don't see how that's possible. You might see a result in the results window, but that's not the same as assigning values to the output parameters, which your procedure does not appear to be doing.

Comment: To be honest though you could just get .net to read the resultset in the normal way. I don't see any particular need for output parameters here. Was there some reason you wanted to do it like that?

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure returns a resultset. It does not return output parameters. In order to return output paramters, SP has to change to something like:

```
select
    @paramout1 = val1,
    @paramout2 = val2
```

Notice "@" that is preceding parameter names.

Comment: issue is resolved after using @parameter
Thank you for the help

Comment: Ravi, would you mind marking the answer as accepted? I am trying to get my reputation score up. Thanks!